# ASP .NET Core websites running on Ubuntu 18.04 NGINX: Possible caching issue

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, asp.net-core

I have multiple ASP .NET Core websites running on Ubuntu 18.04 using NGINX. I notice when I make changes to a website, some changes don't take effect.

Even when I delete every single file and folder from my website directory (/var/www/mysite.com), a webpage still shows at my domain. All the style sheets and images aren't there, but an old version of the homepage is there.

I don't know if this is a caching issue. I have tried different browsers in different locations. I deleted the files from the directory last week and the page still shows today. Can it be an ASP .NET caching issue? Amazon EC2 caching? NGINX caching? Or something else?

My website NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location ~ /.well-known {
        root /var/www/mysite.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's your browser that's caching it unless you explicitly set no-caching header. And some browsers, namely chrome and firefox have some very aggressive client sided caching

Comment: If I go to an online browser test site, like https://www.browserling.com/ and test my URL in a few different browsers, I still see a webpage.

Comment: Does it persist, when you restart the ASP.NET Core application? Do you have one of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/?view=aspnetcore-2.1 enabled?

Comment: Restaring NGINX doesn't help. And I am not using services.AddMemoryCache(); in my Startup.

Comment: Did you also restart the asp.net-core service? Not only nginx sudo systemctl restart my-service-name. Nginx is just the proxy.

Comment: That's not what i asked. Not restarting nginx. Your APP. Nginx is only reverse proxy. That's not tomcat. Also i don't mean memory cache, but the response caching

Comment: "nginx sudo systemctl restart mysite" worked